# Sort DataTable based on two columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, datatable

I am currently have a DataTable populated with data, however, I want to sort it based on two columns before using it.

Here is how my DataTable looks like

DataTable dt:

```
   Date    | Serial Number
22/06/2017 |       2
20/06/2017 |       1
22/06/2017 |       1
20/06/2017 |       2
```

I have research online, and tried `dt.DefaultView.Sort` or `LINQ` but I couldn't get it to work. I have tried these following:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Date, Serial Number";

DataTable newDt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
.ThenBy(r => r.Field<int>("Serial Number")).CopyToDataTable();
```

I tried both of the methods mentioned above and the result I got back was that the sorting was only based on one column, e.g:

```
   Date    | Serial Number
22/06/2017 |       2
22/06/2017 |       1
20/06/2017 |       1
20/06/2017 |       2
```

But that was not what I wanted. Below is what I wanted,

Expected result:

```
   Date    | Serial Number
20/06/2017 |       1
20/06/2017 |       2
22/06/2017 |       1
22/06/2017 |       2
```

May I know if there's any way to perform an operation to sort the DataTable in such manner? Thank you.

Comment: What stops you from sharing the code you have tried ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya nothing's stopping me from sharing. I just wanted to get straight to the point. I could share if you could just ask.

Comment: Its not easy to understand what could be the problem and provide solution if we don't know what you have tried and where you are going wrong. It would be helpful if you can share your code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya as requested, I have updated the post with examples and results.

Answer (score 4):

Following code seem to work for me.

```
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static DataTable Dt;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dt = new DataTable();
        Dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("date", typeof(DateTime)));
        Dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Serial Number", typeof(int)));

        AddRow(Dt.NewRow(), new DateTime(2017, 06, 22), 2);

        AddRow(Dt.NewRow(), new DateTime(2017, 06, 22), 1);
        AddRow(Dt.NewRow(), new DateTime(2017, 06, 20), 2);
        AddRow(Dt.NewRow(), new DateTime(2017, 06, 20), 1);
        foreach(DataRow dr in Dt.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", dr[0], dr[1]));
        }
        DataView dv = Dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "date, Serial Number";
        foreach(DataRow dr in dv.ToTable().Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", dr[0], dr[1]));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void AddRow(DataRow dr, DateTime dt, int serialNumber)
    {
        dr[0] = dt;
        dr[1] = serialNumber;
        Dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ you would use

```
XXX.OrdyBy(o => o.Field1).ThenBy(o => o.Field2)
```

Comment: I have updated the post, do have a look. Thanks anyway!